# Why am I getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building a custom multistep registration form using advanced custom fields in WordPress, I have the form laid out but I am stuck on the jQuery validation with this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Ooops, something went wrong, please try again later.

I can't find out what's wrong with my code.

```
    var epmformdata = {};

    $.each($('#field-group-1 input, #field-group-1 select'), function(i, v) {
        if (v.type !== 'submit') {
            epmformdata[v.name] = v.value;
        }
    }); //end each

    // Do AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data:{
            action: 'epm_registration_process',
            epformdata: epmformdata
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === true) {
                // If user is created

                if(animating) return false;
                animating = true;

                current_fs = $(this).parent();
                next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

                //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
                $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

                //show the next fieldset
                next_fs.show(); 
                //hide the current fieldset with style
                current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
                    step: function(now, mx) {
                        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                        left = (now * 50)+"%";
                        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                        opacity = 1 - now;
                        /*current_fs.css({
                            'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
                            'position': 'absolute'
                        });*/
                        next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
                    }, 
                    duration: 0, 
                    complete: function(){
                        current_fs.hide();
                        animating = false;
                    }, 
                    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
                });
            } else {
                $.each(response, function(i, v) {
                    console.log(i + " => " + v); // view in console for error messages
                    var msg = '<label class="error" for="'+i+'">'+v+'</label>';
                    $('input[name="' + i + '"], select[name="' + i + '"]').addClass('inputTxtError').after(msg);
                });
                var keys = Object.keys(response);
                $('input[name="'+keys[0]+'"]').focus();

                $('.result-message').html( response ); // If there was an error, display it in results div
                $('.result-message').addClass('alert-danger'); // Add class failed to results div
                $('.result-message').show(); // Show results div
            }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**My PHP**

```
// Verify nonce
if( !isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'epm_new_user' ) )
die( 'Ooops, something went wrong, please try again later.' );

//Prepare basic user info
$username = strtolower($_POST['acf']['field_5b4be98fd288c']);
$firstname = $_POST['acf']['field_5b4be9d8d288d'];
$lastname = $_POST['acf']['field_5b4be9e8d288e'];
$email = $_POST['acf']['field_5b4be9f7d288f'];
$password = $_POST['acf']['field_5b4bea0bd2890'];
$cpassword = $_POST['acf']['field_5b4bea8bd2891'];

$error = array();
//IMPORTANT: You should make server side validation here!
if( empty($username) ){
    $_SESSION['errors']['acf']['field_5b4be98fd288c'] = "Please enter a username";
}
if( empty($firstname) ){
    $_SESSION['errors']['acf']['field_5b4be9d8d288d'] = "Please enter your first";
}

if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
    //This is for ajax requests:
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);
        exit();
    }
    //This is when Javascript is turned off:
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $key => $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
         echo '</ul>';
        exit();
}else{
//form validation successful - process data here!!!!

    //Register user
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( 
        /*array(
            'user_login'    =>  $username,
            'first_name'    =>  $firstname,
            'last_name'     =>  $lastname,
            'display_name' => $firstname . ' ' . $lastname,
            'nickname' => strtolower($firstname . ' ' . $lastname),
            'user_email'    =>  $email,
            'user_pass'     =>  $password,  // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
            'role' => 'employer',
        )*/
    );

    // Return
    if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
        echo '1';
    }
    else {
        echo $user_id->get_error_message();
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you'd get that if the following is true `if( !isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'epm_new_user' ) )`

Comment: This question is likely to close because it is a large code dump without much context - only an error and that "something is wrong". If you can narrow it down with some debugging, that would help readers enormously.

Comment: Thank you @Jaromanda you are right, this is why people should sleep lol. It was literally in front of me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the nonce parameter with a valid nonce, when the server side code is called.

For example, assuming you've implemented your code into JavaScript file that you are including using the function wp_enqueue_script

`wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_file', 'http://www.yourwebsitedomain.com/your_js_file.js');`

As the nonce must be generated in the server side you should call the wp_localize_script function to generate a global JavaScript variable with the nonce if the JavaScript file was enqueued (I'll call the global variable, my_global_var):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_file', 'http://www.yourwebsitedomain.com');
wp_localize_script( 'my_js_file', 'my_global_var', array('nonce'=> wp_create_nonce('epm_new_user')));
```

Now, in your JavaScript code you should edit the piece of code:

```
data:{
        action: 'epm_registration_process',
        epformdata: epmformdata
    }
```

as follows:

```
data:{
        action: 'epm_registration_process',
        nonce: my_global_var['nonce'],
        epformdata: epmformdata
    }
```

and that's all.

Comment: Nice right up, I hope it helps someone else.